# Video.js + React & Redux: Cannot read property 'vttjs' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, video.js

Part 1:
I am attempting to build a React component that uses the video.js video player.

This library was chosen because of some out of the out of the box functionality that it provides. Specifically video format conversion and caching.

To implement this I used the code from Video.js' offical docs (or more like soon to be official docs) @ https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/3972/files:

```
 import React from 'react'
 import videojs from 'video.js'

 export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     // instantiate video.js
     this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function onPlayerReady() {
       console.log('onPlayerReady', this)
     })
   }

   // destroy player on unmount
   componentWillUnmount() {
     if (this.player) {
       this.player.dispose()
     }
   }

   // wrap the player in a div with a `data-vjs-player` attribute
   // so videojs won't create additional wrapper in the DOM
   // see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/3856
   render() {
     return (
       <div data-vjs-player>
         <video ref={ node => this.videoNode = node } className="video-js"></video>
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
```

However when I run this code the component seems to work well enough but I'm getting this error in my console: VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'vttjs' of undefined

Full stack trace:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'vttjs' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (vtt.js:1481)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9672f7f…:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 9672f7f…:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9672f7f…:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 9672f7f…:86)
    at tech.js:648
    at Html5.addWebVttScript_ (tech.js:647)
    at HTMLVideoElement.bound (fn.js:32)
    at HTMLVideoElement.data.dispatcher (events.js:284)
```

From the digging I've done this seems to be an issue with Webpack having trouble bundling Video.js' dependencies. There are many threads that reference this error, but I can't seem to find an agreed upon solution (or one that solves the issue for me).

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here? Or perhaps provide some info on a potential solution.

Part 2:
In essence, the task at hand is to build a video editor that would allow the user to crop a video or zoom into part of a video and pan around (like Google Maps but on a video). There are video.js plugins that will provide some of this functionality.

This video player/editor React component will exist in a larger React app that uses Redux to manage state. I'm concerned that it will be very difficult to integrate this Video.js player and its state into a React + Redux app. As the state of the video player/editor is essentially implemented via a black box (video.js and the plug-ins used) that doesn't have an API to interface with Redux.

With all of that said, when an action is dispatched and the state of the app is updated and the App/component is re-render I'm worried that the video player will be re-rendered and its state not preserved as the state of this component is not managed by the Redux store. Or some other kind of weirdness derived from a non-Redux component embedded in a React + Redux app.

I know there is a lot there and I don't believe I'm articulating as clearly as I would have hoped, which speaks to my lack of clarity on this issue. Hopefully some of that makes sense and someone has some knowledge on this type of problem.

Thank you!

Here is the repo I'm using for reference: https://github.com/caseysiebel/videojs-component

Comment: There seems to be a Github issue thread about this. Hope this can help: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2750